# Несколько значений

Tags: javascript

У меня есть код:

```js
var inp = document.getElementById('answer').value;

var sear = 'текст';
var found = inp.match(sear);
if (found) { 
  alert('нашел');
} else {
  alert('не нашел');
}
```

```html
<input id="answer" value="текст">
```

как сделать так, чтобы если `<input>` имел значение ***поезд*** то все равно бы скрипт выдал "нашел", но и при значении ***текст*** скрипт тоже выдавал бы "нашел"?

Comment: вас что интересует то? менять текст в инпуте, и чтобы код реагировал на это?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вижу, вы используете `match`, значит регулярки. Попробуйте так:

```js
var inp = document.getElementById('answer').value;

var sear = /(текст|поезд)/;
var found = inp.match(sear);
if (found) { 
  alert('нашел');
} else {
  alert('не нашел');
}
```

```html
<input id="answer" value="поезд">
```

Answer (score 2):

Ничего не надо делать, это код уже работает так, как написано в вопросе.

Comment: кажется в таких случаях закрывать вопрос надо, а не ответ без содержательной части писать

Comment: @teran Весь ответ целиком состоит из содержательной части. По какой причине вы хотите закрывать вопрос?

Comment: очевидно, "вызван проблемой которая больше не воспроизводится, или опечаткой". Тем не менее, вероятно, автор все же хочет менять текст в инпуте. Так что может быть и "необходимо конкретизировать" либо "непонятна суть"